# $cordovaGeolocation return in an array

Tags: angularjs, ngcordova

I'm trying to do this a few hours and not succeeding.

I have a promise of $cordovaGeolocation returning latitude and longitude very basic equal to the ngCordova documentation.

I want to know how do I return the latitude and longitude in an array I have outside the function.

How can I do this???

Following the code structure.

```
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var long = position.coords.longitude;
  alert(lat + " | " + long);
}, function (err) {
     console.log("fail");
});

var deviceInfo = {
   uuid: uuid,
   dataDevice: [
     {
       model: model
     }
   ]
 };
```

Thank you

Comment: Can anyone help?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getCurrentPosition() {    

    var posOptions = {
        timeout: 10000,
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation
        .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var coordinates = [lat, lng];

            window.console.log("Coodenada:" + " " + coordenada);    
            return coordinates;            

        }, function(err) {
            // error
            console.log(err);
        });



};
```

Comment: +1 for this method. If you want it available in different scopes, you could also save it to a scope variable. e.g. `$scope.coordinates = [lat, lng];`